# Is lshw correct that this hard drive is SCSI not IDE?

Tags: hard-disk, lshw

I have a hard drive (model: ST9100822A), which I think is IDE, because of the look of its interface pins, and accordingly the instruction of my SATA/IDE-USB adapter. But `lshw` shows it as a SCSI disk

```
  *-disk                    
       description: SCSI Disk
       product: 2A
       vendor: ST910082
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/sdb
       size: 93GiB (100GB)
       capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
       configuration: ansiversion=7 guid=42c2216a-4117-4d4e-8273-e307120f9816 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
```

Some search on the internet seems to say that IDE and SCSI disks are different. Is it  a IDE or SCSI disk? Thanks.

More output from `lshw`

```
*-usb:2
     description: USB controller
     product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
     vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
     physical id: 12.2
     bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
     version: 39
     width: 32 bits
     clock: 66MHz
     capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
     configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
     resources: irq:17 memory:f294c000-f294c0ff
   *-usbhost
        product: EHCI Host Controller
        vendor: Linux 4.15.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
        physical id: 1
        bus info: usb@1
        logical name: usb1
        version: 4.15
        capabilities: usb-2.00
        configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
      *-usb
           description: Mass storage device
           vendor: Innostor Technology Corporation
           physical id: 1
           bus info: usb@1:1
           logical name: scsi0
           version: 0.06
           serial: 20140403
           capabilities: usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host
           configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
         *-disk
              description: SCSI Disk
              product: 2A
              vendor: ST910082
              physical id: 0.0.0
              bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
              logical name: /dev/sdb
              size: 93GiB (100GB)
              capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
              configuration: ansiversion=7 guid=42c2216a-4117-4d4e-8273-e307120f9816 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
            *-volume
                 description: data partition
                 vendor: Windows
                 physical id: 1
                 bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                 logical name: /dev/sdb1
                 serial: d25b0434-005b-4880-8f60-85d3590f63c5
                 capacity: 93GiB
                 configuration: name=pimary
```

Comment: if lshw tell you it's SCSI, why do you think it's IDE?

Comment: Because I attach it to my computer by the IDE instruction of my SATA/IDE-USB adapter.

Answer (score 4):

`lshw` is showing you your IDE-to-USB adapter, not your disk. USB disk devices show up as SCSI disks, normally under a “Mass storage device” — basically, there’s a USB device in the `lshw` tree, and a SCSI device, emulated by the USB adapter (as can be seen in the long version of your question: “capabilities: usb-2.10 scsi emulated scsi-host”).

USB mass storage adapters use SCSI commands, so it’s much easier for devices behind USB adapters to be handled as SCSI disks rather than whatever they really are.

The adapter hides the nature of your disk. Since you connected it to an IDE port (presumably 40-pin), it’s an IDE disk, and its model number (ST9100822A) shows up in the disk vendor and product id (“ST910082” and “2A”).

Comment: True, but the adapter does not hide the disk model, since ST9100822A is the model number of a Seagate ATA disk.

Comment: Why does the Mass storage device part shows it is a SCSI disk?

Comment: It's emulated SCSI using the usb mass storage driver (kernel option USB_STORAGE):
"Say yes here if you want to connect USB mass storage devices to your computer's USB port. This is the driver you need for USB floppy drives, USB hard disks, USB tape drives, USB CD-ROMs, USB flash devices, and memory sticks, along with similar devices. This driver may also be used for some cameras and card readers. This option enables the SCSI option, but you probably also need SCSI device support: SCSI disk support for most USB storage devices to work properly."

Comment: @Freddy your comment gives the impression that the driver emulates SCSI, but it’s the device which emulates SCSI (the adapter in this case), as mentioned in the second paragraph in my answer.

Comment: Though if the IDE device uses ATAPI, there's probably not a lot of emulation involved - ATAPI is basically SCSI commands, the bridge just has to repackage them. Which is why IDE disks started to show up as `/dev/sd*` instead of `/dev/hd*` at some point, when the kernel sorted out the SCSI layers, and deprecated the older drivers. ST9100822A is 100 GB, that's new enough I doubt it insists on pure ATA...

Comment: @StephenKitt Yes, that's what I thought. Thanks for correcting me!